# Notation For CDF of Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I recently downloaded a statistical distribution application on my android,
and it lists the CDF for the Binomial Distribution as $I_{1-p}(n-k,1+k)$.
I am not familiar with this notation, and I was hoping someone can explain 
it to me.

Comment: There is no simple expression for the CDF of the binomial distribution, and so the notation means whatever the originator meant it to be. For $0 \leq x \leq n$, the CDF of the binomial random variable with parameters $(n,p)$ is given by $$F_X(x) = P\{X \leq x\} = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \binom{n}{i}p^i (1-p)^{n-i}$$ and I suppose one could call this $I_{1-p}(n-k,1+k)$ if one chose to since the thing _is_ a function of $1-p, n$, and $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation refers to the regularized incomplete beta function.

$$I_x(a,b) = \frac{B(x; a,b)}{B(a,b)},$$

where $B(x;a,b) = \int_0^x t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}\ dt$ and $B(a,b) = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$.

It is not particularly hard to derive this directly from the definition.

Source, for more reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: all I was looking for was $I_{1-p}(n-k,1+k)$= $(n-k)\binom{n}{k}\int_0^{1-p} t^{n-k-1}(1-t)^{k}\ dt$

Comment: Which is not hard to get, simply by substitution. Note however, that the equality you type is not an identity, simply a consequence of that choice of values for $a,b$, and as such the right hand side is not an adequate definition of the notation $I_{1-p}\ldots$, as it is not generally true for non-integer $a,b$.

Comment: The questionable identity I typed came directly from the link you were kind enough to provide with your answer. Wiki seems to equate the two expressions, but I think I will stick with the traditional definition for the CDF of the Binomial. $$F_X(x) = P\{X \leq x\} = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \binom{n}{i}p^i (1-p)^{n-i}$$

Comment: Yes, it is true that the things are equal (in the case where the parameters are integers), but you asked what the notation $I_{1-p}(\cdot)$ meant.

Comment: And I sincerely appreciate your response.

Comment: No problem. In case you're wondering why the CDF is presented in terms of Beta functions, versus the more straightforward summation, it's (partly) because the terms appear explicitly in the derivation of the binomial distribution's conjugate prior distribution. For instance, see the example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior_distribution. Also, beta functions are used for all sorts of things, and it's often easier/more stable numerically to compute the beta functions than the binomial coefficients in the summation.